# How to create a rotating Globe without using webgl as IE9 doesn't support webgl

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have developed a rotating globe in threejs, but I have to do it now without using webgl, and I have no idea how to make it, is there any other 3D language that is supported by internet explorer 9?

Comment: Not without extensions like Unity, Flash or Java

Comment: Thanks, but java as in can u please elaborate , coz unity and flash will require their respective web players to run , and our client wont install any player

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick and easy solution without really have some kind of interactive globe and where you don't expect to modify anything you could try this out.

You can do it via pure CSS. I've used this already.

http://codepen.io/chinchang/pen/xCkus

The idea behind it is to set the background image of a globe to a rounded div and to animate the background on the X axis, from right to left.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="earth"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#earth {
  width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 210px;
    box-shadow: inset 16px 0 40px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0),
        inset -3px 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position-x: 0px; }
  to { background-position-x: 210px; }
}
```

and here is the tutorial that goes along with it:

http://kushagragour.in/blog/2012/09/rotating-earth-using-css/

Comment: Thanks for reply but i need to rotate globe on drag

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use canvas renderer in ThreeJS. Canvas 2D rendering is supported from IE9.

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

It is going to be slow, but it will work. Here is an example taken from [ThreeJS docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/CanvasRenderer):

```
function webglAvailable() {
    try {
        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        return !!( window.WebGLRenderingContext && (
            canvas.getContext( 'webgl' ) ||
            canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' ) )
        );
    } catch ( e ) {
        return false;
    }
}

if ( webglAvailable() ) {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
} else {
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply  but even canvas renderer in ie 9, i tried using examples of three js also

Answer (score 0):

Same as Avenoir, except not relying on CSS3 animation:

```js
console.clear();
document.body.innerHTML = '';
clearInterval(interval);
var imgUrl = 'http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg';
var c = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(c);
c.style['background-image'] = 'url(\'' + imgUrl + '\')';
c.style['background-size'] = 'cover';
c.style.height = '400px';
c.style.width = '400px';
c.style['border-radius'] = '50%';
c.style['box-shadow'] = '0px 0px 100px #000000 inset';
c.style['background-position'] = '0px 0px';
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  var arr = c.style['background-position'].split(' ');
  arr[0] = arr[0].split('px');
  arr[0][0] = (parseFloat(arr[0][0]) + 0.1).toString()
  c.style['background-position'] = arr[0].join('px') + ' ' + arr[1];
 }, 1000 / 60);
```